# Easiest way to make a text string a certain length in HTML

Tags: html

Seems a simple question, but I haven't found a simple answer. I have a certain element  which will be present on a few lines and will be preceded by text strings with different number of characters.

So unoptimized code will look like this:

```
<p>String of a certain length <example></example></p>
<p>String of a different length <example></example></p>
<p>Third string <example></example></p>
```

Problem is I want the example elements to be vertically aligned with each other. So preceding strings should take the same space.

How can I do that?

If it's too complex in HTML, making strings a fixed number of characters will suffice too. I understand that they may have not the same length though.

Comment: you want to display them on block of words or characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can only use plain HTML, the simplest solution might be to just use a table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>String of a certain length</td>
    <td>[element]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>String of a different length</td>
    <td>[element]</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third string</td>
    <td>[element]</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```